# What is Wrong With My InitState in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I am trying to do autologin with flutter and firebase and put it in an initState but it doesn't seem to be excuted because I tried to move it to Build Widget but nothing worked but when I put it inside LoginPageState It was excuted but with error :
**Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.**
My Code :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if (user == null) {
      print('User Null');
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/HomePage');
    }
  }
```

Comment: try create a function outside it and put the code inside , and then call it inside initstate

Comment: try create a function outside it and put the code inside , and then call it inside initstate

Comment: Can you try to put your code inside ? WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) { 
      inal user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if (user == null) {
      print('User Null');
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/HomePage');
    }
    });

Comment: Doing it inside a function didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` to finish. So use `await` as the following.

```dart
final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()
```

Comment: It worked except for adding async to initState because it is imossible so I added async to the **autologin()** function. Thanks :)